# How to find Logistic / Sigmoidal function parameters in Logistic Regression

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, logistic-regression

I want to estimate the best parameters (mentioned at very end : slope and intercept) for sigmoidal / logistic used in logistic regression for a medical data. Here's what I've done python:

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn import preprocessing, svm, neighbors
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression, LogisticRegression
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn import preprocessing, svm, utils
from scipy.io import loadmat
import pandas as pd
```

I have Apache.mat file which contain 4 columns :  Apache score (0-72), Number of patients, Number of deaths, Proportion (ratio of Number of deaths to Number of patients)

```
datamat = loadmat('Apache.mat')
data = pd.DataFrame(np.hstack((datamat['apacheII'], datamat['NoPatients'], 
datamat['NoDeaths'], datamat['proportion'])))

data.columns = ['apacheII', 'NoPatients', 'NoDeaths', 'proportion']
```

Here I've created the dataframe to work with.

```
x = np.array(data.drop(['NoPatients', 'NoDeaths', 'proportion'],1))
```

I've dropped the undesired columns and now only left with ApacheII score in 'x'

```
#scaling the data (normalizing)
x = preprocessing.scale(x)

y = np.array(data['proportion'])
```

Now, I've used LabelEncoder() function to encode 'y' so it could be compatible with LogisticRegression().

```
lab_enc = preprocessing.LabelEncoder()
encoded = np.array(lab_enc.fit_transform(y))

clf = LogisticRegression()
clf.fit(x, encoded)
print(clf.coef_)
print(clf.intercept_)
```

The output is as follows:

```
[[-0.49124107]
[-0.23528893]
[-0.19035795]
[-0.30312848]
[-0.25783808]
 [-0.37161079]
 [-0.12332468]
 [-0.16797195]
 [-0.05660718]
 [-0.21279785]
 [-0.22142453]
 [-0.10105617]
 [-0.14562868]
 [ 0.00991192]
 [-0.012247  ]
 [ 0.03206243]
 [ 0.07635461]
 [ 0.20951544]
 [ 0.12067417]
 [-0.03441851]
 [ 0.16504852]
 [ 0.09850035]
 [ 0.23179558]
 [ 0.05420914]
 [ 1.47513463]]
[-1.79691975 -2.35677113 -2.35090141 -2.3679202  -2.36017388 -2.38191049
 -2.34441678 -2.34843121 -2.34070389 -2.35368047 -1.57944984 -2.3428732
 -2.3462668  -2.33974088 -2.33975687 -2.34002906 -2.34151792 -2.35329447
 -2.34422478 -2.34007746 -2.34814388 -2.34271603 -2.35632459 -2.34062229
 -1.72511457]
```

I just want to find out the parameters for sigmoidal function which is generally used in Logistic Regression. How can I find the sigmoidal parameters (i.e intercept and slope) ?

Here is sigmoidal function (if reference is needed):

```
def sigmoid(x, x0, k):
     y = 1 / (1 + np.exp(-k*(x-x0)))
     return y
```

Comment: If `proportion` is continuous variables, I think for this problem you should be looking for ridge regression rather than logistic regression.

Comment: Yes, you are correct @GergesDib . Thanks. But here I'm just trying to figure out the parameters for logistic function even though it is not the best regression model to go with. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I think you already found them, they are `lr.coef_` and `lr.intercept_`. What's the problem?

Comment: I predicted that there should be one value for `lr.coef_` and `lr.intercept_` and that is what I need. But I'm getting bunch of values. Can you help?

Comment: what's `x.shape` and `y.shape`?

Comment: That's a weird thing! If I print `print(x.shape, y.shape, encoded.shape)` i get this `(38, 1) (38,) (38,)`. I'm not sure how to make sense of this.

Comment: I see.. `encoded` carries class labels, and since `y` is continuous you have 38 unique label (one for each observation), and thus you have 38 coefficients (one for each class). If you replace `encoded` by something like `np.concatenate([np.ones(19), np.zeros(19)])` so it looks like you have 2 classes, then you will get a single coeff and intercept.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is normal behavior of LogisticRegression for multinomial problem solving.
Look [there](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegression.html):

> In the multiclass case, the training algorithm uses the one-vs-rest
> (OvR) scheme
>
> intercept_ is of shape(1,) when the problem is binary.

Examples:

```
>>> clf = LogisticRegression()
>>> clf.fit([[1,2], [1,3], [0, 1]], [[0],[1],[0]])
>>> clf.coef_
array([[ 0.02917282,  0.12584457]])
>>> clf.intercept_
array([-0.40218649])
>>> clf.fit([[1,2], [1,3], [0, 1]], [[0],[1],[2]])
>>> clf.coef_
array([[ 0.25096507, -0.24586515],
       [ 0.02917282,  0.12584457],
       [-0.41626058, -0.43503612]])
>>> clf.intercept_
array([-0.15108918, -0.40218649,  0.1536541 ])
```

In fact there are some models that aiming to solve different binary problems. You can to merge i-th coef and i-th intercept and you'll get model for solving i-th binary problem and so on to end of list.